# Golang interfaces do not need to be imported?

Tags: interface, go

If you take a look at the `File` struct it has a `Read()` and `Write()` function that is exactly the same as `io.Writer` and `io.Reader` interface `Read()` and `Write()` functions. But the package `io` is no where to be found in `File` package (not imported). Does this mean that interfaces do not at all have to be imported to be used? As long as the `Read()` definition is the same as the interface it can then be implied that it is part of the `io.Writer` or `io.Reader` interface?

io: http://golang.org/pkg/io/

os: http://golang.org/pkg/os/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Package `os` does not import package `io` as the `io.Reader` interface is not used in package `os`.

The type `*File` happens to implement `io.Reader` because it has a `Read`method with the right signature. This implements relation is *implicit* and it is neither needed nor possible to make this *explicite* (e.g. like in Java with `implements ISomeThing`).

You asked: "Does this mean that interfaces do not at all have to be imported to be used?" and the formal answer is: Of course *not*! If you want to use `io.Reader` you have to `import "io"`.

But implementing/satisfying an interface is *not* an use of this interface: Any type implements any interface (even future ones which have not been invented jet) just by having the right methods.

Answer (score 1):

Exported entities are constants, variables and types. To use them, ie. to refer to such exported entities, one has to use their [qualified] name, while the qualifier is the basename of the package which exports them. That also implies using an import statement of such package. IOW, binding exported entities in a file scope is [strictly] *explicit*. No import == no access to exported stuff.

OTOH, implementing an interface is [specified](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) to be *implicit*:

> A type implements any interface comprising any subset of its methods and may therefore implement several distinct interfaces. For instance, all types implement the empty interface:

```
interface{}
```